# iOS: Is it possible for me to link the items of a UITableView to call a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm new to iOS and objective-C.

Before I dive down into this I'd like to know if it is possible for me to create a tableview of items that are each linked to a specific URL, so that when I click on an item it switches to a WebView with that specific URL.

Just need to know if this is possible using tableview or if I need to use something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just use a `UINavigationController` and make a URL property in the `UIViewController` that houses the `UIWebView` and when an item in the table view is tapped, set the url property of the web view controller to the proper url and push that view controller to the navigation controller.

Comment: OK that's pretty much what I figured. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some code to help....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGectMake(0,0,320,480)];


 URLViewController *controller = [[URLViewController  alloc] init];
 controller.view = webView;
 controller.urlToShow = @"http://google.com";

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

 [webView release];
 [controller release];

}
```

URLViewController is going to be a subclass of UIViewController. Assuming it has a property called urlToShow, you can then show the URL in the Web View in the viewDidLoad method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *urlAddress = urlToShow;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)self.view;
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```